# VUEJS V-SHOW only toggles first time

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, toggle, conditional-rendering

**How come v-show works only the first time it gets toggled?**

I have an input, `if_motorcycle_owned`. If its value is true, another select input will show, otherwise it won't. 
Here the relevant code:

```
<label for="select-if-moto" class="mt-3">Possiede un motociclo?</label>
 <b-form-select
   name="select-if-moto"
   type="select"
   v-model="currentProfile.if_motorcycle_owned"
   :options="boolean"
   @change="onChangeMoto($event)"
   class="mb-2"
   required
 />
<div  v-show="currentProfile.if_motorcycle_owned === true">
  <label
      for="select-info-moto"
      class="mt-3"
 >
Indica la cilindrata
</label>           
 <b-form-select
   id="select-info-moto"
    type="select"
   v-model="currentProfile.user_motorcycle_characteristic"
   :options="motoEngine"
   class="mb-2"
   required
 />
 </div>
```

The function @onChangeMoto isn't doing anything, just console.log in which I can see the changes of the boolean values are detected.

```
onChangeMoto(event) {
  console.log('if moto from profile: ', this.currentProfile.if_motorcycle_owned)
},
```

I am not using any v-for in the template.
I tried settin a variable itShows: false in data() and then

```
this.itShows = !this.itShows
```

inside the @onChangeMoto to kind of force the toggling but nothing changed.

The default values are coming from an api response, if I start with true, the other div will show, if I select false, it disappears, as expected. 
**But after the first time, if I keep toggling it doesn't change anymore.** Only the values in the console, as you can see:

```
if moto from profile:  false
if moto from profile:  true
if moto from profile:  false
if moto from profile:  true
if moto from profile:  false
```

Does anyone know why???
Thanks

Comment: My guess is that the values being set by the input are Strings, rather than Booleans.

Comment: I actually have filter to custom true false value for the UI ```boolean: [
        {
          text: 'Si', value: 'true'
        },
        {
          text: 'No', value: 'false'
        }      
      ],``` Can it be this? I thought about it but couldn't find much....

Comment: It is exactly as @RoyJ wrote. You even explicitly coerce the values to a string by using your quotation marks :)

Comment: Jeez.... :/// Thank you. I can't believe I did it and moreover, didn't notice it. Thanks again.